# WebStorm typings in external libraries

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am trying to update my **react-router** library from version 5 to version 6.

I have updated my `package.json` file and the library installs correctly in my "nodes" folder.

However I have noticed that there is this annoying WebStorm/IntelliJ typing folder called `Project @types` under "External Libraries".

[image]

This contain old typings from react-router version 5.

On closer inspection I noticed that it is under my `AppData`:

[image]

Why does this exist? Where does it come from? And can I just delete it?

**UPDATE**

I have tried deleting it, but magically it recreates the folder again :( . This is really really annoying. I do not want my project dependant on some old typings in some `AppData` folder; I want it dependant on the typings in the "nodes" folder.

Answer (score 2):

IDEA downloads typings for some popular libraries to its configuration folder and uses it to enhance code completion. Please try to either disable `typescript.external.type.definitions` Registry key or remove `react-router-dom` from `typescript.external.type.definitions.packages` key value and then remove the auto-downloaded typings from `<IDEA system folder>\javascript\typings` folder.

The Registry can be located via: **Help > Find action** > type `Registry...`